# commands to send messages in Python via the Poplib module?

Tags: python, email, poplib

I've found a number of tutorials online involving downloading messages via Poplib, but haven't been able to find anything explaining how to create new messages.  Does this exist?

Answer (score 3):

As S.Lott rightly says, you will want some smtp, but to create the actual email, use the [email](http://docs.python.org/library/email) package from the standard library, then use an message's as_string method to send it.

[An example with multipart MIME (how cool is that!)](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/52243/)

Answer (score 2):

Send yourself an email to create a message.

SMTP is the protocol the email uses to send.  In Python, you'd find this in [smtplib](http://docs.python.org/library/smtplib.html).

There are numerous email RFC's.  Here are a few.

SMTP - [RFC 821](http://www.faqs.org/rfcs/rfc821.html)

POP - [RFC 1939](http://www.faqs.org/rfcs/rfc1939.html)

IMAP - [RFC 1730](http://www.faqs.org/rfcs/rfc1730.html)